# Xampp Mysql and Apache not Working - How to backup database

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I'm having trouble with my Mysql and Apache server here for a week already. Tried to look for every possible solutions in the internet like changing ports and everything. Still no luck. I would like to reinstall Xampp, the problem is, I have important databases which do not have any backups yet. Is there a way to backup these databases without having my apache and mysql started?

Comment: yes, the data directories and below. the ones with the frm, myd. If you have been reading all over as you say, you would know the dirs, and how to bring them in later

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on the type of storage engines you're using.

### MyIsam

MyISAM tables are stored as files, so it is easy to do a backup by copying files (`*.frm`, `*.MYD`, and `*.MYI` files). In a typical XAMPP installation they can be found under `c:/your/path/to/xampp/mysql/data/` .

### InnoDB

Have a look at the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.5/en/innodb-backup.html):

> 1. Copy all InnoDB data files (ibdata files and .ibd files) into a safe place.
> 2. Copy all the .frm files for InnoDB tables to a safe place.
> 3. Copy all InnoDB log files (ib_logfile files) to a safe place.
> 4. Copy your `my.cnf` configuration file or files to a safe place.

However, if you have important databases, it is advised to think about a backup strategy *before* problems occur. MySQL offers a variety of backup strategies from which you can choose the methods that best suit the requirements for your installation.

Comment: i have done this before but it resulted into empty or missing tables

Comment: Please clarify. MyIsam? InnoDB? If done properly, you shouldn't run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just copy the data files. for innodb you need the ibdata1 (or similar) file. For MyISAM you will see 3 files (different extensions) for each database and the filename match the database names. If it is MyISAM then you can just copy these files back into the data directory on your new install and it will just work.

The other thing you should do is not use WAMP! It is easy enough to set up from scratch and much easier to figure out when things don't work.... you just need to read a *little* bit.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the files in your **htdocs** to another location first, duplicate the database organizers from information envelope and erase xampp then re-install it. You also need to delete the ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 files from the data folder inside mysql folder.
Read here for further procedure https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3437/lost-tables-in-drupal-site-database